# Decimal.TryParse but with NumberStyles?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use Decimal.TryParse to give a descriptive message back to the user when a value is failing (in the actual code, I pass in an item number that the user can then use to go back and fix). However, 3,5 seems to be okay with Decimal.TryParse (the 3,5 was a typo of 3.5. I know normally in the US commas are for ease of reading and are safely ignored though usually separating in blocks of 3 from right to left starting at the decimal) whereas when I use NumberStyles with Parse, it does not. How can I get 3,5 to fail the try parse?

```
using System.Globalization;

string test = "3,5";
Decimal val;

if (!Decimal.TryParse(test, out val))
{
  throw new Exception("Error: " + test + " is not valid.");
}
// at this point, val is now '35'
val = Decimal.Parse(test, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint); // fails
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Or is my best course of action to rewrite the if to check for the comma?

```
if (!Decimal.TryParse(test, out val) || test.Contains(","))
```

Comment: I believe you need to provide the specific culture as a 3rd parameter.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question with an [mre] of your attempt to use corresponding [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-7.0)? So far it is quite unclear how passing NumberStyles to `TryParse` did not work for you...

Comment: `if (!Decimal.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Float, null, out val)) {...` ?

Comment: The result of executing this code depends on the current culture.

Comment: `var provider = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = "" }; if (!Decimal.TryParse(test, provider, out val))` - Specify the format provider in which the group separator is missing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton is correct. I was trying to find a Decimal.TryParse(string, NumberStyles, out Decimal) to be analogous to Decimal.Parse, but when I tried, the IDE only shows the (string, IFormatProvider, out Decimal) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get 3,5 to fail the try parse?

The simple answer is to disable the "AllowThousands" flag on NumberStyles. For example:

```
decimal.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Any ^ NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val)
```

If you want TryParse behavior to match the behavior of Parse, you'll want to use the same NumberStyles on TryParse that you are using on Parse. TryParse doesn't have an overload which takes NumberStyles without also taking an IFormatProvider, but you can explicitly pass `null` into the IFormatProvider argument in order to get the same behavior.

```
string test = "3,5";
Decimal val;

if (!Decimal.TryParse(
    test, 
    NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
    null, 
    out val))
{
  throw new Exception("Error: " + test + " is not valid.");
}
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

The default behavior without an `IFormatProvider` is to use the current culture, which could lead to unexpected behavior and difficult-to-reproduce bugs. Consider using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or possibly the specific culture that has the behaviors you're looking to match.

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* use the overload to `TryParse` that takes a `IFormatProvider` argument, or rather a culture.

Most of the time, one uses one of two forms:

```cs
if (Decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var number)
{
    // ....
}
```

or

```cs
if (Decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var number)
{
    // ....
}
```

The first format is used when the data to parse is user input and it is expected to be in the user's locale. So depending on where you are, the dot will either be the decimal separator, or the thousand's separator. Or neither. The second format is used if the data is e.g. from a file and always has the same format. It uses a '.' as decimal separator (and a ',' as thousands separator, but this is typically not used in this case).

Additionally, you can specify your own custom format preferences, either by specifying an explicit `NumberFormatInfo` with e.g. `var provider = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = "" };` or by providing a particular culture e.g. with `CultureInfo us = new CulturInfo("en-US");`.

So there's no "one correct" solution, it depends on the context and of what the  user is assuming.